# How to sort an array of the objects of a class according to a numeric property of the class

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I store objects of a class in an object array of the same class.

```
MyClass[] objectsOfMyClass = new MyClass[9];
```

Now I want to sort in descending order the objects stored in the array according to a numeric property of the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
objectsOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.NumericProperty)
```

For your information, this is using [Linq to objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx). It will not sort the array but return an IEnumerable that's ordered correctly.

```
var orderedArray = objectsOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(m => m.MyProperty).ToArray();
```

The `ToArray` might not be necessary depending on what you're doing with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.Sort()` method overload, which accepts `Comparison<T>`:

```
Array.Sort(objectsOfMyClass, (o1, o2) => o2.NumericProperty.CompareTo(o1.NumericProperty));
```